# How to change the Magento export order CSV layout?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change the export orders CSV column layout. For example, it is showing the following column

Order #
Purchased On
Bill to Name
Ship to Name
G.T. (Base)
G.T. (Purchased)
Status

Check my screenshot http://take.ms/d3OVH

But I want it like following

Sales Record Number
Buyer Full name
SKU
Quantity
Post To Address 1
Post To Address 2
Post To City
Post To County
Post To Postcode
Post To Country

Check my screenshot http://take.ms/jloSf

Thank you